# map data into put and select the selected item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data like this

```
"dates": {
"contract": [
      {"id":1,"name":"1 month","value":false},
      {"id":2,"name":"2 months","value":true}
    ]
}
```

How can I mapped it into a select HTML? I did this

```
<select className="form-control">
    {item.dates.contract.map(obj => 
        <option value={obj.value} >{obj.value}</option>
    )}
</select>
```

It worked partially, it rendered but now I'm stuck at selecting the option.

Comment: Do you mean default selected item?What item do you want to select by default?

Comment: You should use `return` statement,

Comment: @Ejaz as you can see it should select 3 months since its value is true.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai return statement is not needed as map without the {} auto return. Anyway, return doesn't' solve my problem, I can render.

Comment: what about "2 months"?

Answer (score 1):

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectValue: [true]};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({selectValue: [event.target.value]});
  }
      render() {
      var item = {
          "dates": {
            "contract": [{
              "id": 1,
              "name": "1 month",
              "value": false
            }, {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "2 months",
              "value": true
            }, {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "3 months",
              "value": true
            }]
          }
        };
      
        return <div>
<select className="form-control" multiple="true" value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {item.dates.contract.map(obj => 
        <option key={obj.id} value={obj.value} >{obj.value.toString()} - {obj.id}</option>
    )}
</select>
        </div>;
      }
    }



    ReactDOM.render( < MyComponent / > ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I don't get this, why u need onChange?

Comment: take a look on the react documentation --> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: Instead of defining selected on each option, you can (and should) simply write value={optionsState} on the select tag itself:

Comment: Got it but I also have bunch of warning when I used selected on the options tag.

Comment: Use the defaultValue or value props on <select> instead of setting selected on <option> , take a look on my snippet i didn't use selected attribute

Comment: You use state, my case is I don't need state, my data come from api, the option field is dynamic.

Comment: I posted a new question to describe my problem better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623937/form-submission-using-react-without-having-state

Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/69z2wepo/72485/)**.

You shoud just use the `selected` attribute like `selected={obj.value}`, e.g :

```
return <select className="form-control">
    {item.dates.contract.map(obj => 
        <option value={obj.value} selected={obj.value}>{obj.value}</option>
    )}
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually there shouldn't be multiple selected, my mistake, what I want is a dropdown.

Comment: this is the old way of doing it, I got bunch of warning.