# Form submission using react without having state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple scenario. User click on an edit button, he go to a page with form filled on every fields. He change something and click save, very simple. In jquery we just bind and get the values from the DOM, in angularjs 2 way binding works the same, but how about in react?

I often seeing people get the form value by binding the input to onChange, but in the edit case, the user might not touch every fields. I don't think state is needed. I need to bind my data

```
var item = {
    "name":"James",
    "dates": {
    "contract": [
          {"id":1,"name":"1 month","value":false},
          {"id":2,"name":"2 months","value":true}
        ]
    }}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p1pztpcw/

I have one more problem. I got warning of `Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you problem with `<select>`, [React is able to read the props `value`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) on `<select>`. As a result, using `selected` on `option` with React is deprecated.

For your problem about creating a state or not, you can avoid it by, when submitting the form, reading each of the inputs value. Each input can be accessed using [React `ref` propertie](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element). But you'll have to bind each of the inputs:

```
<input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
```

Comment: Regarding using ref, any alternative for a better solution? Says you have 20 fields in one page, how you handle the form submission?

Comment: @Mellisa the better solution is to use onChange.

Comment: @Melissa: using `onChange` or `ref`, you'll have to declare something on each input. If you don't want to, you can continue using jQuery.

Comment: @DamienLeroux no one simplify this issue? if I have 30 fields, means I will have 30 onChange function name, that's tiring and messy.

Comment: @Melissa: For this case, you can create an object: `const inputProps={onChange}` to gather the common props required for all inputs, then use the spread operator to give `inputProps` to each input: `<input {...inputProps}/>`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use on change and call the single function. And you can use a switch statement if you want inside that function.

Regarding the warning: use

```
<select value={obj.id}>
```

instead of specifying it in

```
<option selected="true">
```

Comment: select tag is at outside of the map function, obj is not defined.

Comment: yes...so you have to precompute it and then display

Comment: like store it in state as defaultval:1
and then use <select value={this.state.defaultVal}>

Answer (score 0):

Using `refs` you can access to input fields, and for select you have to handle when it changes. You don't need to handle everything, and even if you were using Redux you could not modify the state, so you could not have a handle event and call to `this.setState(...);`

Basically you can access to the value directly using `this.refs.refName.value` or you can use a function to set the value like this `ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }}` and then access it via `this.input`.

You can read the full docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

For default value on `select`, according to [ReactJS docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) using `value={this.state.value}` is OK. If you are getting a warning it could be caused by other reason.

In the case you were using frameworks like Redux, where you cant (or you should not) modify the state, you should dispatch an action on `handleChange` instead of setting the state.

But If you dont want to use `handlres` neither `refs`, then you should think to move from ReactJS. I prefer using refs because It feels cleaner.

Here you have a working example:

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  handleSave: function(){
    alert('name: ' + this.refs.input.value)
    alert('selectValue: ' + this.state.selectValue)
  },
  render: function() {
    var item = {
    "name":"James",
    "dates": {
    "contract": [
          {"id":1,"name":"1 month","value":false},
          {"id":2,"name":"2 months","value":true}
        ]
    }}

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={item.name} ref={'input'}/>

        <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} >
          {item.dates.contract.map(obj => 
            <option value={obj.id}  selected={obj.value}>{obj.name}</option>
          )}
        </select>
    <button onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)}>Save form</button></div>)
  },
  handleChange:function(e){
    this.setState({selectValue: e.target.value});
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

### JQuery

Using JQuery is not recommended by ReactJS Team because JQuery takes away the control of the DOM from ReactJS at all, that could derive in undesirable behavior. It is suposed that we have chosen ReactJS to control the DOM for us. And really there is no need to use JQuery at all.

Comment: How curious how will it be in redux, don't handle the selection means?

Comment: Instead of calling `this.setState({...})`, you dispatch and action: `this.props.dispatch(actions.selectedChange(newValue))`. One of the three Redex's principles is **Unmutable state**. So the selected option keep starred in the store. That's why you would need to access input via refs, otherwise means you would be dispatching an action everytime the value is modified.

Comment: you know about alt? it's a flux library. How does that look like in alt? don't mutate the state too?

Comment: I dont know what alt is.